# Почему я не могу расширить динамический массив?

Tags: c++, массивы, динамические-массивы, fstream

> Вот есть файл текстовый в котором записаны данные вот так:
> Tree 4.6 44 Apple 5.7 4 Goodtree 3.0 5 sometrees 55.9 70  в каждой строке по Имя(стринг) высота(дабл) и урожайность(инт). Я пытаюсь создать динамический массив структуры который будет хранить в себе информацию из этого файла(выгрузит). Идея сделать так что по количеству строк в файле произведётся столько итераций соответсвенно и столько же будет равна size значит такого размера будет массив. Но выводит бяку и то что я написал не работает, индекс мне ужен для работы с массивом потом.

```
void fillArr() {
   int size = 1;//размер массива
   int index = 0;
   tree* p_arr1 = new tree[size];//создание динамического массива
   fstream stream;
   stream.open(path, fstream::in | fstream::out);
   bool toggle = true;
   while (toggle)
   {
       stream >> p_arr1[index].name;
       stream >> p_arr1[index].hight;
       stream >> p_arr1[index].yield;
       cout << p_arr1[index].name << "\t" << p_arr1[index].hight << "\t" << p_arr1[index].yield << endl;
       size++;
       index++;
       if (stream.eof()){
           toggle = false;
       }
   }
   
   stream.close();
};
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Размер массива не меняется после его создания. И тем более он не должен меняться от изменения какой-то int переменной.

Comment: Используйте std::vector, он решит проблемы увеличения размера массива автоматически.

Comment: @nevilad да использовал бы но я не знаю как они работают, а времени учить их нету.

Comment: @Lazy_student_economic , `std::vector<int>a;` - создание вектора с типом хранимых переменных int. `a.length()` возвращает размер вектора. `a.push_back(_int_)` - добавляет элемент в конец, `a[i]` - возвращает элемент с индексом i. `a.pop_back()` - удаляет последний элемент. Это основы, которые достаточно знать, чтобы более-менее с векторами работать. Можно использовать указатель (http://cpp.sh/33esl), но на свой страх и риск, так как он может изменить другую переменную или же указать на несуществующий объект.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С вектором будет выглядеть так:

```
void fillArr() {
  std::vector<tree> vTree;
  fstream stream;
  stream.open(path, fstream::in | fstream::out);
  while (1)
  {
    tree elem;
    stream >> elem.name;
    stream >> elem.hight;
    stream >> elem.yield;
    vTree.push_back(elem);
    cout << elem.name << "\t" << elem.hight << "\t" << elem.yield << endl;
    if (stream.eof())
        break;
  }
  stream.close();

  //Вывод содержимого вектора
  cout << "Vector contents:" << endl;
  for( const auto& elem : vTree )
    cout << elem.name << "\t" << elem.hight << "\t" << elem.yield << endl;
};
```

Выход из цикла чтения файла пока не найден `eof`, в общем случае неверный. Могут возникнуть ошибки чтения. Для обычного выхода из цикла достаточно вызвать инструкцию `break`, не нужно вводить для этого отдельную переменную.

Answer (score 0):

Предоставлю ООП подход.
Я создал класс *Tree* который перегружает операторы ввода и вывода

*tree.h*

```
#ifndef TREE_H
#define TREE_H

#include <string>
#include <fstream>

class Tree {
private:
    std::string name;
    double height;
    int efficiency;

public:
    std::string getName() { return this->name; }
    double getHeight() { return  this->height; }
    int getEfficiency() { return this->efficiency; }

public:
    Tree();
    Tree(std::string _name, double _height, int _efficiency);

    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& in, Tree& obj);
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, const Tree& obj);
};

#endif // TREE_H
```

*tree.cpp*

```
#include "tree.h"

Tree::Tree() : name(""), height(0), efficiency(0) {
}

Tree::Tree(std::string _name, double _height, int _efficiency) : name(_name), height(_height), efficiency(_efficiency) {
}

std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& in, Tree& obj) {
    in >> obj.name;
    in >> obj.height;
    in >> obj.efficiency;

    return in;
}

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, const Tree& obj) {
    out << obj.name
        << ' '
        << obj.height
        << ' '
        << obj.efficiency;

    return out;
}
```

*main.cpp*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <list>
#include "tree.h"

#define FILE_NAME "input.txt"

int main() {
    std::list<Tree> trees;

    std::ifstream inFile(FILE_NAME);
    if (!inFile) {
        std::cerr << "Cannot open file: " << FILE_NAME << "; Exiting";
        return 1;
    }

    Tree temp;
    while (inFile >> temp) {
        trees.push_back(temp);
    }

    for (const Tree& tree : trees) {
        std::cout << tree << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Я использовал связный список, но, в случае необходимости, переделать под *vector* так же просто, как заменить все слова *list* на *vector* в `main.cpp`

Comment: Я заметил чаше используют потоки istream ostream вместо универсального fstream, почему?

Comment: @Lazy_student_economic `std::fstream` является суперклассом `std::iostream`, а тот, в свою очередь, суперклассом  `std::istream` и `std::ostream`. Следовательно, если метод принимает `std::fstream`, то компилятор разрешит вызов метода, не зависимо от того, передается ли ему входной или выходной поток. Из за этого придется проверять в самом методе, какой именно поток он получил. В случае использования `std::istream` и `std::ostream` компилятор исключит возможность неверного вызова, защитив вас от ошибок во время выполнения. [Подробнее здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30388453/13435478)

Answer (score -3):

Прочитав ваш комментарий, пришел к выводу, что вам нужен динамический массив без помощи STL. Некое подобие динамического массива можно создать при помощи указателя:

```
void fillArr() {
   int size = 1;
   int index = 0;
   int* p_arr1 = new int(0)

   bool toggle = true;
   while (toggle)
   {
       cin >> *p_arr1;
       if (*p_arr1==0){
           toggle = false;
       }
       p_arr1++; //следующий элемент
       size++;
   }
   p_arr1-=size-1; //переход к начальному элементу
   for (; *p_arr1!=0; p_arr1++) {
       cout << *p_arr1 << " "; //вывод каждого элемента, кроме нуля
   }
};
```

Однако высок риск, что указатель изменит другую переменную. Кроме того, если не применить
`delete p_arr1;` для каждого элемента после использования массива, эти элементы останутся в памяти вплоть до завершения программы.

Comment: `высок риск, что указатель изменит другую переменную` еще более высок риск, что вы получите ошибку сегментации. Это ведь доступ к памяти, которая не принадлежит вашей программе, **UB**. Тут уже не просто `на свой страх и риск`, никогда так не делайте!